If $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $X^{*}$, so does its convex combination?

Suppose $X$ is a reflexive normed space and let $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $X^{*}$. Let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence where each $g_n$ is made up of finite convex combination of $\{f_1,f_2,\ldots, f_n\}$. (Additional comment: If this sequence comes from Mazur's Lemma, we know $g_n \to f$ strongly in $X^{*}$.)


$(1)$ Is $\{g_n\}$ weakly convergent in $X^{*}$?


$(2)$ Does there exists a subsequence $\{g_{n_k}\}$ of $\{g_n\}$ such that $g_{n_k}\rightharpoonup f$ weakly in $X^{*}$?

Attempt: I can't make any substantial progress on either. However, unpacking the definitions, we have:
Since $X$ is reflexive, $f_n \rightharpoonup f$ in $X^{*} \implies$ $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ for all $x$ in $X$. Let $$g_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{i,n} f_i$$ where $0 \leq \lambda_{i,n} \leq 1$ and $ \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_{i,n}=1.$
As $\{f_n(x)\}$ is bounded for each $x$ in $X$, so is $\{g_n(x)\}$. Passing to a subsequence, define $$g(x):=\lim_{k}g_{n_k}(x).$$ Thus, $(2)$ is partially true, but I can't seem to find a way to show whether it is possible to have $g=f$.
Any insights would be really helpful.

Suppose $f_1 \neq f$ and $g_n = f_1$ for all $n$. Then clearly $g_n \to f_1 \neq f$, so (2) cannot be true.

As long as $f_1 \neq f_2$, you can just set $g_n = f_1$ when $n$ is odd and $g_n = f_2$ when $n$ is even. Then $g_n$ does not weakly converge. So (1) is not true either.

For your partial result on (2), while you’re certainly right in your result (at least when $X$ is separable), your proof is a bit problematic. I’d suggest using uniform boundedness principle, then just apply Banach-Alaoglu.

Also, if $g_n$ is instead a finite convex combination of ${f_n, f_{n+1}, \cdots}$, then you actually do have $g_n$ weakly converging to $f$. Might that be what you actually need?

@DavidGao Thanks for the suggestion. How would one show that $g_n$ converges to $f$ weakly in that case?

@approximation Fix $x \in X$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Suffices to show there exists $N$ s.t. $|g_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. As $f_n \to f$ weakly, there exists $N$ s.t. $|f_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$ whenever $n \geq N$. Since $g_n$ is a convex combination of ${f_n,f_{n+1},\cdots}$, we have $g_n(x)$ is a convex combination of ${f_n(x),f_{n+1}(x),\cdots}$, so by triangle inequality, $|g_n(x)-f(x)|$ is bounded by some convex combination of ${|f_n(x)-f(x)|,|f_{n+1}(x)-f(x)|,\cdots}$, which is in turn bounded by $\epsilon$, i.e., $|g_n(x)-f(x)| \leq \epsilon$, as required.
